# Validation Rule

Tags: validation-rule

I am pretty new to Validation rules, this validation throws an error even if the field is 10 digits long.
I have to bound users to populate the field no more than 10 digits

```
AND(
NOT(ISBLANK(USI_Number__c)), 
NOT(REGEX(USI_Number__c, "(\\d){10}"))
)
```

Comment: What should happen if they enter less than 10 characters?

Comment: it should give a validation error

Answer (score 0):

There is the `LEN` function which returns number of characters in a string, so your validation should be something like:

```
NOT(ISBLANK(USI_Number__c)) && (LEN(USI_Number__c) >= 10 || NOT(REGEX(USI_Number__c, "(\\d)")
```

Comment: This is not letting me save the field even if the numbers are 10

Comment: My apologies, use `>=10` instead of `>10`

Comment: No its not working still its still giving an error

Answer (score 0):

Validation rule always checks for error condition to be true. So if the formula you have written in the validation rule is evaluating to true it will throw error.

Update:

I tried following validation rule:

```
AND(
NOT(ISBLANK(temp_number__c )),
NOT(REGEX(temp_number__c , "(\\d){10}"))
)
```

I tried this and it works absolutely fine for your conditions. Only one addition to it. You must have created a Text field 'USI_Number__c' , enter its length as 10.

Hope this solves your problem. :)

Comment: No i have to restrcit users if they populate the field they should always put 10 digits

Comment: @Jovi yes that's what the formula above does......did you try that?

Comment: Yes its still giving an error  AND( 
!ISBLANK(USI_Number__c), 
LEN(USI_Number__c)<>10)

Comment: @Jovi have updated my solution...please check!!!

Answer (score 0):

AND( 
!ISBLANK(USI_Number__c), 
LEN(USI_Number__c)<>10)

This works